# Given a power spectral density of a signal. How to find mean of the signal?

Tags: power-spectral-density

Given a stationary process signal with PSD
$$
S_u = \Lambda(f)
$$

How to find the mean, power, and variance of the signal? 
I know how to find power given PSD (integrating from -inf to inf over f). But I am unable to determine how to find the mean. Any insight is appreciated.

Edit: 
Mean = $E\{x(t)\} =  \lim_{T->\infty}\frac{1}{T} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x X(t)\,\mathrm dx$

Power =$E\{|x(t)|^2\} =  \lim_{T->\infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x X(t)X(t) \,\mathrm dx$ 
Variance = $E\{|x(t)|^2\} - (E\{x\})^2$

Comment: Hint: It might be helpful if you state what _you_ think are the meanings of the words "mean, power and variance" of the signal; with appropriate mathematical formulas, not words.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I have edited my question and included the mathematical formulation for the mean,power and variance. But I am unable to tell how to find the mean. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Unfortunately, your integral formulas are totally incorrect.  If the mean is nonzero, the PSD will have an impulse at $f=0$. The magnitude of the impulse will give you some clues as to what the nonzero mean is.